# Python - return date and time value and use it later

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following code, but I'm not quite sure how it's going to work.

I'll execute the following:

```
date = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

and it will return exact date and time of the moment I call this. I want to use the exact output of this date and time in another function which is going to be execute 2-3 seconds later.

How can I pass the date variable here and not use the new current time and date?

Comment: Do you have the full code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does anything stop you from passing `date` as a parameter to your other function ?

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_functions.htm

If you can't pass it as a parameter, and both functions are within the same object / class, you can use `self.date = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")` and on your other function use `self.date` when you need to read it.

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects

Finally you can simply set a global variable, but depending on your project, this may cause bugs, if for example the code is multi-threaded (like a web application).

[Using global variables in a function other than the one that created them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function-other-than-the-one-that-created-them)

Comment: i've test code as following :  def ready():
   readyDate = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
   print  readyDate
   return;

Comment: when ever i call this , it will give me the current date and time for sure , my code include differents functions one of these function will use  def ready and get output o it which is should be 2-3 sec behind ..